# How to access laptop directories on desktop?

Tags: networking, files, directory, sync

I'm currently facing the following problem: I have a desktop computer at home and a laptop that I use for school and work projects in the field.

Usually, many small files are created on my laptop system, related to whatever I'm working on and since it is not my main machine, I commonly just leave them all in the documents folder. However, this makes it just a mass, because I have files in two places and need to get them onto my desktop.

Is there a way besides transferring them with a USB drive (which also only works one way), maybe to connect my laptop directories to my home network or even connect both machines via USB cable and access those files from my desktop computer? This would allow me to use a synchronisation software to get the new project files off my laptop directory and maybe even push new music files that I regularly get on my desktop to my laptop's music folder at the same time.

However, I think that the software needs to see the laptop directories as normal folders for this to work (I'm using FreeFileSync currently for other purposes) and, of course, I also do not want every network to see my laptop's directories.

Comment: if you do not want to share folders on the laptop, you could still copy the needed files to a shared network folder and then from that folder to the wanted place on your desktop. Also, do you have Wifi? would be easier to connect to the network with a wifi connection. If not, you will have to have an ethernet cable available for the laptop hookup for the file transfers. Just remember to not share any folders from the laptop if you do not want seen on your network.

Comment: How about installing Dropbox (www.dropbox.com) on both? Your files will be uploaded from your laptop to the cloud. You start your PC and it will automatically download new/changed files.